# Ros::Timer, will stopping it with .stop() cause its counter to restart?

Tags: timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

If I declare a basic timer like this:

```
ros::Timer my_timer = nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(1), callback);
```

And then I stop it like this (say, 0.5 seconds later):

```
my_timer.stop();
```

And then I start it again like this:

```
my_timer.start();
```

Will the timer start again at the beginning of its counter (0 sec), or will it start up from where it left off (0.5 sec)?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11308/ros::timer,-will-stopping-it-with-.stop()-cause-its-counter-to-restart?/) by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 353 on 2011-09-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The timer will start again at the beginning. The stop() method cancels all pending callbacks and lets the timer forget about the time that has already elapsed.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6